# Catching/Fixing a Run-time error

Tags: vba, excel

> Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number

I would like to ask for your help and suggestions as to why my code encounters a "run-time error '52': bad file name or number" when I am using a computer which do not really have access to the directory drive. I tried it on my personal computer and it showed the run-time error.

My code is working fine when I am using our company computers which have access to the directory drive. And it displays the message box "unable to access" if I try to change the folder name to make it inaccessible (for troubleshooting purposes).

What I am trying to do is actually display a message box just in case the computer used do not have any access to the directory.

I tried searching around, tried using "", 0, and vbNullString. But no success. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
'Check if all fields are filled up.
If Wbb.Sheets("Report").TextBox3.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please check missing data."
Else
    'Check if drive is accessible, if not prompt a message
    If Dir(filePath1, vbDirectory) = "" Then 'this is where the run-time error is pointing at
        MsgBox "Unable to access drive. Please save file manually."
        Exit Sub
    Else
    'Check if folders exists in drive. If does not exist, create folders.
       If filePathCheck <> "" Then
           aDirs = Split(filePathCheck, "\")
           If Left(filePathCheck, 2) = "\\" Then
               iStart = 3
           Else
               iStart = 1
           End If

           sCurDir = Left(filePathCheck, InStr(iStart, filePathCheck, "\"))

           For i = iStart To UBound(aDirs)
               sCurDir = sCurDir & aDirs(i) & "\"
               If Dir(sCurDir, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
                   MkDir sCurDir
               End If
           Next i
       End If
    End If
```

Comment: use `on error goto ...`

Comment: Can you please show an example what `filePath1` contains if the error occurs? The only thing I can think why this error is thrown is if `filePath1` contains an `UNC` path like "\\Servername\\SharedFolder\Resource\" and this path is not available over the network. It this is true for you, see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/vba-code-to-check-if-a-sharedrive-is-available/dd909386-63e5-4988-bd7c-05b305de82bd?auth=1.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, you are correct that filepath1 is UNC path which is \\bmptdat085\Working\Users\. Thank you for the link. It works great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dir()` throws an error if the left part of the directory does not exist. However the `FileSystemObject` simply returns `False` without throwing an error.

```
Public Function FolderExists(ByVal Path As String) As Boolean
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        FolderExists = .FolderExists(Path)
    End With
End Function
```

No reference the the `Scripting.Runtime` required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am accepting this as the best answer as I have researched that this way is the fastest and most efficient way to check if a network drive is available. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of what [@Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) said in your comments, use Error Handling - [[1]](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) - [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement) - [[3]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/handle-run-time-errors-in-vba)

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 52
            MsgBox "~"
            ' Possibly pop up a save dialog if you desire
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox "!"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative solution. I learned a lot in error handling in VBA. It works okay with my macro. Thanks again.